# Implementing a search and results page in the admin interface

Tags: 7, forms, search, paging

I'm trying to implement a search and results form in the admin interface but I am having trouble getting the search function and pager working.

[1] The pager is not showing at all. I've got this working using db_select for the query but I'd like to use a solr query. How can I get a pager to display?

[2] The form submission is not working as expected either. On submission the page is redirect to the correct url but an error message is displayed: The requested page `'/admin/monitor/custom/search/?q=foobar'` could not be found. Do i have to declare a separate menu route /admin/monitor/custom/search/% to handle searches?

Many thanks,

```
function custom_menu(){
    $items['admin/monitor/custom/search'] = array(
      'title' => 'Custom',
      'description' =>'Custom search form',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('custom_form'),
      'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
    );
    return items;
}

function custom_form($form, &$form_state){

    $table = build_results_table();

    $form['keyword'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#description' => t('Search database by keyword'),
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Go!'
    );

    $form['results'] = array(
      '#markup' => $table,
    );

    return $form;
  }

function build_results_table($search_term){

    // perform query using Solr Search API
    // page number from $_GET('page')
    // search limit from a variable set by another module
    $results = query_database();

    $header = array('Firstname', 'Middlename', 'Surname');

    $rows = //... build rows from $results ...;

    $table = theme('table', array(
      'header' => $header,
      'rows'=>$rows,
    ));

    pager_default_initialize($table);
    $table .= theme('pager');

    return $table;
}

function custom_custom_form_submit($form, &$form_state){

    $keyword = $form_state['values']['keyword'];
    drupal_set_message(t('Showing results for %keyword',
    array('%keyword' => $keyword)));

    $form_state['redirect'] =
    '/admin/monitor/custom/search/?q='. $keyword;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Drupal only has only pager implementations for DB queries, but you can use the pager system manually for data in external sources. There are a couple of examples on the [`pager_default_initialize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/pager_default_initialize/7) docs that should get you started.
2. Anything other than `q` as the param name should work - Drupal uses `q` as the path param in its rewrites, so it's probably trying to find a route of `foobar` in your example.

Comment: Thanks, [1] I got the pager to display by adding the correct parameters to  pager_default_initialize($count, $limit). However I now have an issue of incorrect 'page' path parameters as described here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/189708/modifying-pager-link-page-numbers. The first page results are displayed on both page 1 and 2. [2] I replaced 'q' as a path parameter with 'search' and now it works. Cheers!

Comment: "Incorrect" to you (and me as it happens), but not to Drupal! That's a long standing issue of contention, I believe the only answer is to roll your own pager implementation. Didn't even make it into D8 as it happens: https://www.drupal.org/node/1818040

Comment: Oh no! Is there not a way of changing the links in a pager preprocess function?

Comment: Links, yes, but not the functionality that handles them; it's hard-coded to start from zero in at least `pager_default_initialize()`, probably others too (other functions probably rely on zero-based indexes without adjustment too). I think that's why the only advice I've seen is to implement your own mechanism